# Does Common Lisp have the fastest PCRE implementation?

Tags: perl, performance, common-lisp, pcre, jit

A friend claimed that **Common Lisp has the fastest Perl-compatible regular expression library of any language, including Perl** itself, because with an optimizing JIT compiler like SBCL, CL-PPCRE can compile each particular regex down to native assembly whereas other implementations, include Perl's, must generate bytecode and interpret it. In practice, especially for the common case where we try to match the same regex against many inputs or long input, the compilation overhead is more than justified.

Unfortunately, I can't find any benchmarks on this, and I don't know enough to run my own, so I turn to the hive mind. Can anyone evaluate this claim?

Comment: SBCL does not have a JIT compiler. SBCL always compiles everything straight to machine code. What SBCL has is that its compiler is always available - even from user code via the functions EVAL, COMPILE and COMPILE-FILE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no benchmarks of my own to share, but perhaps your friend was referring to results concerning the portable regular expression library [CL-PPCRE](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/).  The current web page no longer speaks of benchmarks, but courtesy of the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20080624164217/http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/#bench) we can see that it used to show benchmark results where CL-PPCRE outperformed Perl 2-to-1.  Benchmarking is a tricky business (especially for moving targets), which might explain why the current page is silent on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

PCRE library has a JIT compiler module now, and it has a good performance compared to other regexes: http://sljit.sourceforge.net/regex_perf.html or http://blog.rburchell.com/2011/12/why-i-avoid-qregexp-in-qt-4-and-so.html